# Multiple recyclerviews using one adapter

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I have an app where I want to use recyclerviews in different parts of the application and I was thinking of using the same adapter for the same two (or more) recyclerviews, I was thinking this would be a good practice, or am I mistaken and better off making a new adapter for every recyclerview in the app?

Here is the code for my adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Task> list;
//This is the list of the second recyclerview which I want to implement
private ArrayList<String> categories;
private OnItemListener mOnItemListener;

RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Task> list, OnItemListener onItemListener)
{
    this.list = list;
    this.mOnItemListener = onItemListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_view, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(textView, mOnItemListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getTaskName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    TextView textView;
    OnItemListener onItemListener;

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.singleView);
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        onItemListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public interface OnItemListener
{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
}
```

So how would I go about doing this so that it can switch depending on which recyclerview in the app is setting/initializing the adapter, so that the `getItemCount` for example, would return the size of `categories` instead of `list` and so on.

Comment: asking if something is a good practice is pretty opinionated, there isn't really a right or wrong when it comes to that. `RecyclerViewAdapter` is just a class, you can pass in any amount of variables you want to it so that it can do the logic you need. or just create multiple, up to you

Comment: If multiple recycler view uses same resources and layout then I don't see any reason to create multiple adapter classes

Comment: Alright thank you, but the main question was not if it was a good practice or not, it was just a part of it so you can skip that part in that case.